# Error calculating rate of growth conditional on one column

Tags: python, pandas, rate

I would like to calculate the rate of growth between two years (1992 and 2000) conditional on a variable (grid100). My goal is to create a new column, called "rate_growth", which gives me for each grid100 the rate of growth of variable "nights"

According to other answers in stackoverflow, I am trying the following:

```
df['rate_growth']= df.assign(pct_change=df.groupby(['grid100']).nights.pct_change())
```

However, it gives me the following error: "ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (6868, 4)".

Any idea how can I solve that issue?

This is an image of how my dataframe look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) it assign new column to original `DataFrame`, so it return all original columns with new assigned one, so cnnot assign to column `rate_growth`:

```
df = df.assign(rate_growth=df.groupby(['grid100']).nights.pct_change())
```

If want assign to column `rate_growth` remove `assign` function:

```
df['rate_growth']= df.groupby(['grid100']).nights.pct_change()
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Thank you also for explaining why my code was not working. It's really useful to know it.